# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException:

Tags: java, serialization, automation, deserialization, rest-assured

I am trying to create an E2E Rest-Assured API automation flow for an E-commerce project.

I am using Pojo classes and serialisation/deserialisation in order to help with this.

Here I am trying to login to BaseUri called https://rahulshettyacademy.com with parameters '/api/ecom/auth/login'. I have tested this manually with my login and password in Postman & it is working fine. But I am having issues in automating it.

This is my code for the main API class:

```
import io.restassured.builder.RequestSpecBuilder;
import io.restassured.http.ContentType;
import io.restassured.specification.RequestSpecification;
import pojo.EcommerceLoginRequest;
import pojo.EcommerceLoginResponse;


import static io.restassured.RestAssured.given;


public class ECommerceAPITest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        
     RequestSpecification req = new RequestSpecBuilder().setBaseUri("https://rahulshettyacademy.com").setContentType(ContentType.JSON).build();
     
     EcommerceLoginRequest loginRequest = new EcommerceLoginRequest();
     loginRequest.setUserEmail("imtiyaz_@hotmail.co.uk");
     loginRequest.setUserPassword("786Immy110.1");

     
    RequestSpecification reqLogin = given().log().all().spec(req).body(loginRequest); 
    EcommerceLoginResponse loginResponse = reqLogin.when().post("/api/ecom/auth/login").then().log().all().extract().response().as(EcommerceLoginResponse.class); 

    
    
    System.out.println(loginResponse.getToken());
    System.out.println(loginResponse.getuserid());
    
    
    
    }

}
```

The below is the code from the pojo class which is called 'EcommerceLoginResponse':

```
package pojo;


public class EcommerceLoginResponse {
    
    String token;
    String userid;
    String message;
    
    public String getToken() {
        return token;
    }
    public void setToken(String token) {
        this.token = token;
    }
    public String getuserid() {
        return userid;
    }
    public void setuserid(String userid) {
        this.userid = userid;
    }
    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }
    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }
    

}
```

Upon running the main test, I am getting the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "userId" (class pojo.EcommerceLoginResponse), not marked as ignorable (3 known properties: "token", "userid", "message"])
 at [Source: (String)"{"token":"eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJfaWQiOiI2NGVhMmQ1MDc1M2VmYTQ2NTdmMDBiNDMiLCJ1c2VyRW1haWwiOiJpbXRpeWF6X0Bob3RtYWlsLmNvLnVrIiwidXNlck1vYmlsZSI6MTIzNDU2Nzg5MSwidXNlclJvbGUiOiJjdXN0b21lciIsImlhdCI6MTY5MzA3NjIwNywiZXhwIjoxNzI0NjMzODA3fQ.SZYf86-UPkQwy9UmZEsbt16cNDmYfnLcpRLgGa_aa1A","userId":"64ea2d50753efa4657f00b43","message":"Login Successfully"}"; line: 1, column: 306] (through reference chain: pojo.EcommerceLoginResponse["userId"])
```

Any ideas on where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is response key is `userId` not `userid`.

**Solution 1**: change the property name and getter/setter.

```java
String userId;

public String getUserId() {
    return userId;
}
public void setUserId(String userid) {
    this.userId = userid;
}
```

**Solution 2**: use Jackson annotation and don't care the properties name and getter/setter

```java
@JsonProperty("userId")
String userid;
```